# What is the probability of guessing 5 digit code with three attempts?

Tags: probability

I want to find the probability of guessing 5 digit code with three attempts. I think of using Bernoulli formula, so it must be
$${5 \choose 3} (\frac{1}{9})^{3}(1-\frac{1}{9})^{2}$$
Am i right?

Comment: Well it should be [chance you get it the first try]+[change you get it the second time, given you didn't get it the first time]+[change you get it the third time, given you didn't get it the first or second time] so $\frac1{10^5}+\frac1{10^5-1}+\frac1{10^5-2}$

Comment: I doubt it.  Could you explain what Bernoulli's formula is and why you think that mean this is the answer.  The $5 \choose 3$ seems to be that somehow you are trying to choose the position of $3$ of the $5$ digits but I don't see what that'd have to do with actually *guessing* the complete numbers and .... well, It looks you you are trying to guess five numbers and figuring out the probabililty that exactly three of the five from 1-9 are in the correct place and exactly two of them are not.  Which is a very different question than what you asked.

Comment: @JacobClaassen Wouldn't it be chance you get it on first guess plus chance you got it on the second guess *given you didn't get it on the first guess*?  So $ \frac 1{10^5} + \frac {10^5-1}{10^5}\frac 1{10^5} + \frac {(10^5-1)(10^5-2)}{10^510^510^5}$?

Comment: It will make a difference whether your second and third attempts might repeat an earlier attempt.  If you won't repeat then it is simply $\frac{3}{100000}$.  I am assuming $10$ possible digits.  Does your use of $9$ mean that $0$ is excluded?